# How to add button to the right of search into navigation bar in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, navbar

In iOS6 we had a navigation bar with a "back button, Search box and a button the right of search leading to the next page.

in iOS7 we lost the button to the right of search.

Can anyone please help me, I'm unable to figure out what to do.